# implementing oData inlinecount using asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, jsonp, odata, asp.net-web-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OData pagination with WebApi ( $inlinecount )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706479/odata-pagination-with-webapi-inlinecount)

Since Asp.net WebAPi almost supports odata, its very enticing for me to get $inlinecount to work so that it plays nicely with kendo ui ( or any other).
So that it returns value in jsonp format, i implemented a new MediaFormatter ( from Stackoverflow).

Trouble is that it needs the results to have count element in them in order to get server side paging to work, so for now i hacked the formatter to get a fake count to work. This all works great and the grid is all happy, however getting the real count is a challenge since IQueryable expression being returned already has filters/Take etc applied to it.

```
 public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        string callback;
        if (IsJsonpCountableRequest(out callback))
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var q = value as IQueryable<Movie>;
                var count = q.Count(); // this count doesnt return the actual count
                var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(callback + "({");
                writer.Write(@"""d""");
                writer.Write(" : { ");
                writer.Write(@"""results""");
                writer.Write(" : ");
                writer.Flush();
                base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, stream, contentHeaders, transportContext).Wait();
                writer.Write(",");
                writer.Write(@"""__count""");
                writer.Write(" : ");

                writer.Write(string.Format(@"""{0}""", count));
                writer.Write("}");

                writer.Write("})");
                writer.Flush();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, stream, contentHeaders, transportContext);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to get the a count separately, may be from the underlying provider of the IQueryable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/supporting-odata-inlinecount-with-the-new-web-api-odata-preview-package/

It uses the latest Web API OData package.

Comment: Any chance of you moving this answer over to the Q I cited as a dup and VTCing (assuming you agree that is) and I'll upvote over there? (If you disagree I can remove the comment)

Comment: Thanks for the move -  that's one happier tidy-freak!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact issue last week. Check out [Extending your ASP.NET Web API responses with useful metadata](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/extending-your-asp-net-web-api-responses-with-useful-metadata/)

I used this post and sample code to get a paging grid up and running using OData. As detailed in the sample I created a delegating handler to capture the HttpResponseMessage and wrap it in custom metadata that includes an item count. A custom attribute, CustomQueryableAttribute, is also created that inherits the default QueryableAttribute.

It may sound a little complex here but is actually pretty simple to implement. I had something up and running in about 30 minutes.

Hopefully future versions of the Web API have more complete OData support.

EDIT: **Odata support will NOT be shipping with the Web API.** The queryable attribute is being removed for the RTM release. More complete OData support will be available sometime after the initial relase via a separate Nuget package.

Comment: See [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12091786/11635) too

Comment: Any chance of you moving this answer over to the Q I cited as a dup and VTCing (assuming you agree that is) and I'll upvote over there? (If you disagree I can remove the comment)

Comment: post moved to post moved to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706479

Answer (score 0):

The SPA `DataController` (which is derived from the `ApiController`) used to implement this functionality. However, with the latest changes, it has been removed, as they plan to support OData in a different manner.

If you're working with the MVC 4 Beta, then you can simply change your controller to a `DataController`, and you're set. If you're using the RC, then you should take a look at an older ASP.NET Webstack [commit](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8ff0d2799efc#src/Microsoft.Web.Http.Data/DataController.cs) on Codeplex. The method you're interested in is `ExecuteAsync`, from *DataController.cs*

Comment: see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706479/odata-pagination-with-webapi-inlinecount