# $inlinecount not working on ApiController using ApplyTo

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to use the OData filtering and paging capabilities in a standard Web API 2.2 `ApiController`. For this, I have to rewrite the request URL to conform to the OData v4 standards. My controller looks like this:

```
public GridPage Get([FromUri] GridSearchCriteria criteria)
{
    Request.RequestUri = ... // convert querystring to OData v4
    var context = new ODataQueryContext(MyEdmModel.Instance, typeof(Delivery), null);
    ODataQueryOptions<Delivery> options = new ODataQueryOptions<Delivery>(context, Request);

    IQueryable<Delivery> deliveries = ... // use EF to load deliveries from DB
    var result = (IQueryable<Delivery>)options.ApplyTo(deliveries); // BTW, I wonder why there is no generic overload of ApplyTo?

    // fill and return a GridPage
    ...
}
```

So far everything works nice as expected.

Now, I'm interested in the total count of the filtered items and thus I've added `$inlinecount=allpages` to the query string. The resulting request URI looks like this:

`http://localhost:54026/.../deliveries/page?$top=10&$skip=0&$inlinecount=allpages}`

Then, I'm trying to retrieve the total count like this (after the call to `ApplyTo`):

```
long? totalCount = Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount;
```

Unfortunately, `totalCount` always stays null no matter what I try. I've also tried using:

```
object totalCount;
Request.Properties.TryGetValue("System.Web.OData.TotalCount", out totalCount);
```

but no luck. A peek into the `Request` properties reveals that there is an entry under `System.Web.OData.Properties` but all its properties are uninitialized (`Model` is null, `NextLink` is null, `TotalCount` is null, etc.).

Does anybody have an idea why this isn't working? BTW, I'm using `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` v5.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to specify `$count=true` instead of `$inlinecount=allpages`. According to https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/web-api-and-odata-v4-queries-functions-and-attribute-routing-part-2/ this was a breaking change somewhere.

Comment: This is working on ODataController as well. This is so poorly documented - thank you!

Comment: Thanks. This helped me w/ other spec changes when I migrated to 4.0: [OData Version 4.0 Part 2: URL Conventions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html)

Comment: it's for OData V4, which inlinecount is replaced with count, not 2 or 3,

i have same issue on ApiController, inlinecount=allpages doesnt work, brign normal result